# jQuery iPhone Style Ajax Switch - IE Error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using this jQuery Plugin - http://papermashup.com/jquery-iphone-style-ajax-switch/

And in IE 8, I recieve the following error:

> Message: Invalid argument. Line: 12
>   Char: 12949 Code: 0 URI:
>   jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Would anyone have any idea as to what the cause of this is and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the non minified version of the jquery library to your site temporarily. That way you can use firebug to get a clearer picture of what is failing in IE8.

This should hopefully point you in the right direction or else you can post some example code of your markup which is failing with the plugin.

Finally, there is also a new official mobile version of jQuery which has this specific control within it. Although it's designed for mobiles you can also use it on any webpage.

See [this link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/#docs/forms/forms-switch.html)